# Add toggle sidebar to blogger template

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger

I try to add toggle sidebar to my blogger template like: https://boardwalkdemo.wordpress.com/

But... something is wrong - whole code may be.

Now i try to show/hide

```
jQuery$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sidebar-toggle').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if ( ! $('body').hasClass('sidebar-open') ) {
            scroll_top_position = $('body').scrollTop();
            scroll_left_position = $('body').scrollLeft();
        }
        $('body').toggleClass('sidebar-open');
        $(this).toggleClass('toggle-on')
             .attr('aria-expanded', $(this).attr('aria-expanded') === 'false' ? 'true' : 'false');
        $('#sidebar').attr('aria-hidden', $('#sidebar').attr('aria-hidden') === 'false' ? 'true' : 'false');
        if ($('body').hasClass('sidebar-open')) {
            $('.site-main').hide();
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: 0,
                scrollLeft: 0
            }, 0);
        } else {
            $('.site-main').show();
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: scroll_top_position,
                scrollLeft: scroll_left_position
            }, 0);
            heights();
        }
    });
```

based on wordpress code but don`t work.

I can see my work in progress here: http://blog.detelinmarkov.com/

Where is my mistake?

I work on header now and may be not work properly part of it.

Comment: Change jQuery$ to either jQuery or $

Comment: As @PushkerYadav said - use `$(...` or `jQuery(...`, not `jQuery$(...` . Also enclose this with `})`

Comment: in your blogger code, before executing this code , js interpreter throwing some console error which are not related to this code, first fix that than check

Comment: I try but don`t work, may be i have other problems. I will try to format first everything in header and then i will try again with toggle button. Thanks for help.

Comment: I fix header but jquery toggle don`t work... When click on button -> noting.

Comment: `Sorry, the blog at detelin-markov.blogspot.com has been removed. This address is not available for new blogs.`

Comment: I change domain to blog.detelinmarkov.com